# Perl: Find key for a hash of arrays

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap

```
    my %hash1 = (
    a => ["turkey, mexico"],
    b => ["india, china"],
    c => ["england, vietnam"],
    d => ["usa"],
);
```

I want to obtain the key related to mexico.
How can I get that?

Tried :

```
print @($a{$hash1{"mexico"}})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I’d build a reverse hash that maps single countries to keys.

Comment: @amon: I thought of creating it the other way but wasnt sure if the mapping would increase a whole lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe if you either iterate through the hash keys and return the array containing it, or if you create another hash.  For the second, it might look like this:

```
my %newhash;
for my $key (keys %hash1) {
  my @list = split /, / => $hash1{$key}[0];
  # or perhaps: my @list = map split(/, /, $_), @{ $hash1{$key} };
  for (@list) {
    $newhash{$_} = $key;
  }
}
$newhash{mexico} eq 'a'; #true
```

This isn't terribly efficient, but it will work.

Comment: Almost… If you look at the hash iDev actually has, you'll see that each arrayref contains only one string like `"turkey, mexico"`, not multiple strings of which one would be `"mexico"`.

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed helpful

Comment: @amon - you're right, I totally didn't see that.  In that case, you'd need to split the string before the second for loop in order for this to still work.  Updated the code to show this.

Answer (score 2):

```
print grep { $hash1{$_}[0] =~ /mexico/ } keys %hash1;
```

and in the case that hash values are arrays with multiple elements,

```
print grep { grep { $_ eq "mexico" } @{$hash1{$_}} } keys %hash1;
```